# Why need front end stores firebase token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, rails-api

I am making a web application. Front side is react, server side is rails api and I use firebase authentication.
Now, I get firebase token and set authorization header whenever calling rails api as below.

```
client.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    config.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    config.withCredentials = true
    var token = await firebaseApp.auth().currentUser?.getIdToken()
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    return config
  },
  (error: AxiosError) => {
    throw new Error(error.message)
  }
)
```

But, I found some ways to store token, unsafe local storage, http only cookie.
Why need front end stores firebase token? Is it bad to get the token every time calling rails api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase ID Tokens are basically [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/), signed by Firebase.
Now imagine a scenario where you need to identify the user in your server. You will probably pass the user's UID in the HTTP Request, which is not safe as that can be easily bruteforced unless you have some sort of rate limiting in your server.

**What I meant by signed?**

A JWT looks something like: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`

The data stored in above JWT is:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

You need to [verify](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) those Firebase IDTokens using Firebase Admin SDK. I don't know if that works with Ruby but worth checking the link above.

Verifying those will either return an object with user auth info or an error if that is an invalid JWT.
You must always pass this JWT in you REST requests to your server because these cannot be bruteforced. Anyone can make a JWT (IDToken) with same content but they don't know your signature. They will need your Firebase Service Account credentials to do so.

Also, JWTs expire eventually (I assume after an hour). So it's not bad to get token again and again. That's what they are meant for. Short term access.

I recommend you to watch this [JWT Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Q17ubqLfaM).
Just be sure to pass the idToken to your REST API to authenticate users and not their UID.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see.